# format - undefined is not a function for Date object

Tags: javascript, date, format

I have following code:

```
 var actualDate=new Date();
 actualDate.format("YYYY-mm-dd HH-MM-ss.l");
```

My browser complains about second row:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript [`Date` objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9) don't have a `format` function built in. If you want one, you'll have to add it to `Date.prototype`, either directly or via a library.

It's not just a name thing, either: JavaScript's `Date` objects just don't have a formatting function at all. They have various functions you can use to *build* one, and they give you `toString`, `toUTCString`, `toLocaleString`, and `toISOString`, but those don't let you control the format.

Comment: can you advice something if I want parse String as Date according format from my question ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) is probably the most flexible, actively-developed date library for JavaScript at the moment. It has significant parsing abilities.